# Hooking of CreateFile throw exception: Read Access violation

Tags: c++, exception, hook

When i run my program it successfully createfile but when I tried to inject my CreateFile API into my program it shows exception

```
   Exception thrown: read access violation.

   pbCode was nullptr.
```

I have search from various sites but still unable to locate the problem
This is the code for hooked CreateFile

```
_CreateFile TrueCreateFile = 
(_CreateFile)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"kernel32"), "CreateFile");
HANDLE WINAPI HookCreateFile(
_In_     LPCTSTR               lpFileName,
_In_     DWORD                 dwDesiredAccess,
_In_     DWORD                 dwShareMode,
_In_opt_ LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes,
_In_     DWORD                 dwCreationDisposition,
_In_     DWORD                 dwFlagsAndAttributes,
_In_opt_ HANDLE                hTemplateFile)
   {    

      HANDLE out = TrueCreateFile((LPCTSTR)"C:\\Users\\abc\\bar.txt",
      dwDesiredAccess,
      dwShareMode,
      lpSecurityAttributes,
      dwCreationDisposition,
      dwFlagsAndAttributes,
      hTemplateFile);

return out;
}
```

To Hook CreateFile

```
void hook_CreateFile()
{
   HANDLE hProc = NULL;
   if (Mhook_SetHook((PVOID*)&TrueCreateFile, HookCreateFile)) {
    // Now call OpenProcess and observe NtOpenProcess being redirected
    // under the hood.
    hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,
        FALSE, GetCurrentProcessId());
    if (hProc) {
        printf("Successfully opened CreateFile: %p\n", hProc);
        CloseHandle(hProc);
    }
    else {
        printf("Could not open CreateFile: %d\n", GetLastError());
         }
    }
   }
```

Comment: Does GetProcAddress return a non-NULL value? Have you tried it with `CreateFileW`?

Comment: No, I haven't tried it with CreateFileW

Comment: When I tried it with CreateFileW exception dose not show but file also not created

Answer (score 0):

TrueCreateFile is a pointer to the function's address.

You're passing `&TrueCreateFile` which is the address of the pointer.

You're hooking the pointer instead of the function.

Just pass `(void*)TrueCreateFile`